# Jenkins can't login on Google accounts from Selenium FireFox webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins

I have a major problem which I can't find a fix for a few days. I made an automated test in Java which logins on Google Gmail. I integrated the test with Jenkins and when it runs it's get stucked when he has to enter the Password. So he enters the user credentials in the correct field, he clicks the next button but in the next screen where the Password field should be present, Jenkins doesn't see it. I tried to locate the element and see if it's present and nothing, It's like it doesn't actually doesn't reach that page.
If I run the test normal from Eclipse there are no issue present, the test runs well so the elements are identified properly.

Please help me, thanks

```
public static void sendEmail() throws InterruptedException{
    driver.get("http://accounts.google.com");
    WebElement element2 = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
               .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("Email")));
    System.out.println("email is present");
    driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("my email@gmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("next")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println("user on");

    WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
               .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("Passwd")));
    System.out.println("Element is present");
    driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("my pass");
    System.out.println("pass on");
    driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
    System.out.println("clicked on sign on");
```

Comment: Please post some relevant code and show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please post the code by editing your original question.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up guys. Jenkins stops right after the line with the System.out.print(user on), the next element can't be located in Jenkins :(.

Comment: What is the exception thrown?

Comment: It's for the Thread.sleep that I use

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Google Blocks testexecutions on in its products say gmail or youtube. to  do this. enable Less Secure App Access and then try it out. also. to properly mimic the user behaviour pass user agents to via scripts.